JPA Controllers, no se conecta a phpMyadmin
Me encuentro con este problema, al ejecutar JPA Controllers, no se conecta a phpMyadmin, y sale estos errores, que se los mostraré en las imágenes:
Espero que me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.
PD: Tengo netbeans 17 y JDK17.
[

Verifica la imagen, esta borrosa. Por favor, corrige la imagen y pega el error como texto al editar la publicación.

Con mucha dificultad, dice que el driver jdbc no fue encontrado. Realizaste una correcta instalación del mismo ?

De todas maneras, los errores son texto... por qué los pones como imagen? Y por encima borrosa. Pégalo como texto, que para eso a ti el programa te lo da como texto. Qué necesidad hay de complicarle la vida a la gente que te intenta ayduar??

Pero no me lo bajes a retos al pobrecito novato, quizás ni se dió cuenta que puso la imagen en mala calidad @Benito-B

Se diese cuenta o no, según las reglas no se debe poner texto como imagen. No todos podemos cargar las imágenes, aún cuando estas tengan buena calidad.
